# how to pass result 'repeat'-'h:selectOneRadio' to List on Backing bean,using Ajax

Tags: jsf-2, uirepeat, selectoneradio

how to pass the result of `<ui:repeat>` `<h:selectOneRadio>` in List on Backing bean, using `Ajax`?

```
<h:form rendered="#{lessonBean.TEST!=null}">
      <ui:repeat value="#{lessonBean.TEST.questions}" var="quest">
             <h:selectOneRadio value="">
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="${quest.a1}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="${quest.a2}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="${quest.a3}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="${quest.a4}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="${quest.a5}"/>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
      </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `lessonBean.TEST.questions` is a list of `Question` objects, you can add to `Question` class new `Integer` field called `answer` (with getters and setters) and do something like:

```
<h:form rendered="#{lessonBean.TEST!=null}">
      <ui:repeat value="#{lessonBean.TEST.questions}" var="quest">
             <h:selectOneRadio value="#{quest.answer}">
                     <f:ajax event="click" process="@this" update="@this">
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="${quest.a1}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="${quest.a2}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="${quest.a3}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="${quest.a4}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="${quest.a5}"/>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
      </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```